# Is it possible to list only blobs with a name matching a pattern with the Azure SDK?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The way I had to phrase this question makes me think "I'm doing it wrong" but I haven't really gotten how this is supposed to work. The way I have it set up now is that I prefix blobs with an identifier of a user and then follow it with something identifying the entity the blob represents, ending with a type identifier and file type. So the format for an image entity with a thumbnail would be something like

```
12345-abcdefg.media
12345-abcdefg.jpg
12345-abcsefg-t.jpg
```

The `.media` blob is a serialized representation of the entity. So, is there a way for me to get the blobs of just this user without enumerating every blob in the container? Should the user have it's own container? Appreciate any help in getting my head around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you just need to list blobs by prefix. CloudBlobClient.ListBlobsWithPrefix should do the trick.

Having separate containers per user may be even easier.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.